# Dental plosives without top teeth

Tags: phonetics, articulation

I have practically never had my front right tooth because of skateboarding, and even before that I crawled off onto a parking block - after that I learned Vietnamese without retroflexing the S. Now im just asking Is the dental plosive possible with the apical against the lower row of teeth or is it more frequent with the top row because of obstructing air on the apical.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apex of the tongue against the lower teeth does not block the airflow enough to make a plosive. The tongue against the front of the palate right behind where the teeth would be (the alveolar ridge) is probably the most similar area to the teeth in terms of what acoustically the plosive would sound like.